# std::vector passed by reference is not passing from a function to main()

Tags: c++, function, c++11, vector

This question is very similar to some other questions that have been posted on here, but nonetheless, it does not seem to work when I implement previously suggested solutions.  I am writing what should be some simple software that can be used to read in one column or multiple columns of data from a .txt file in a function and pass it to the main program for further calculations.  The function call passes the file name to the function and reads in the data.  Since this version only reads in one columns of data I could use a return function for this specific example, but I plan on expanding this to read in multiple columns of data so that is why I am using a void function. The column of test data is shown below.

```
103.816  
43.984  
2214.5    
321.5     
615.8     
8.186    
37.6
```

The for loop in the function Read_File reads back the data from the file perfectly indicating that the function works fine and properly reads in the data.  However, when I try to display the same data using the same for loop in the main program i get an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS fault.  To be clear the program compiles fine, but it is not passing the data to the main program, which indicates a pointer problem.  Where am I going wrong with this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

class Read_Columnar_File {
public:
    void Read_File(const std::string& file_name,std::vector<float>& Column1);
};

#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int i;
    std::vector<float> Column2;
    Read_Columnar_File File1;

    char str[20];
    std::strcpy(str,"Test.txt");

    File1.Read_File(str,Column2);

    std::cout << std::endl;
   for(i = 0; i < 7; i++) std::cout << Column2[i];
}   

void Read_Columnar_File::Read_File(const std::string& file_name,std::vector<float>& Column1)
{
    int i;
    std::ifstream inp(file_name,std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if(inp.is_open()) {
    std::istream_iterator<float> start((inp)), end;
    std::vector<float> Column1(start,end);
    for(i=0; i < 7; i++) std::cout << Column1[i] << std::endl;
    }
    else std::cout << "Cannot Open " << file_name << std::endl;
    inp.close();
}
```

Comment: `Read_File` implementation declares and manipulates a local variable named `Column1`. It never touches a parameter by the same name. These two variables are distinct and unrelated. Change `std::vector<float> Column1(start,end);` to `Column1.assign(start, end);`

Comment: It is not necessary to manually close `inp`, it does so automatically when it goes out of scope. You also don't need to provide `ios::in` flag to `ifstream`.

Comment: I changed std::vector<float> Column1(start,end) to std::vector<float> Column1.assign(start,end) and it would not compile.  I had to write it as std::vector<float> Column1 and then on the next line Column1.assign(start,end).  But even though it compiled, it still did not pass the array to the main program.

Comment: You don't need to write `std::vector<float>` at all, as you don't want to create a new vector variable, but use the existing one.

Comment: Wait, never mind, as RADAR mentioned I need to declare vector<float> Column1 as a public variable in the class definition.  Sometimes it is amazing how I can miss such simple things.  Thank you for pointing out the assign issue to me, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: RADAR did not say to make it a public variable in the class definition. This issue has nothing to do with public and private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix the issue. column1 is locally declared.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Read_Columnar_File {
public:
    void Read_File(const std::string& file_name, std::vector<float>& Column1);
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int i;
    std::vector<float> Column2;
    Read_Columnar_File File1;

    char str[20];
    std::strcpy(str, "Test.txt");

    File1.Read_File(str, Column2);

    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) std::cout << Column2[i];
}

void Read_Columnar_File::Read_File(const std::string& file_name, std::vector<float>& Column1)
{
    int i;
    std::ifstream inp(file_name, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (inp.is_open()) {
        std::istream_iterator<float> start((inp)), end;
        Column1.assign(start, end);
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) std::cout << Column1[i] << std::endl;
    }
    else std::cout << "Cannot Open " << file_name << std::endl;
    inp.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are declaring a local variable `std::vector<float> Column1(start,end);` inside the function

the local variable is being assigned the values, so actual vector is not updated.

Comment: Thank you, such a simple thing to forget about the differences between public and private.